# Complexity of finding $\alpha(G) + \omega(G)$

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

The CLIQUE NUMBER problem is NP Complete (due to correspondence with $3$-SAT); so is the INDEPENDENCE NUMBER problem (since $\omega(\overline{G}) = \alpha(G)$, or from CHROMATIC NUMBER problem). Can anything be said about the complexity of finding $\alpha(G) + \omega(G)$ ?

Since $\omega(\overline{G}) = \alpha(G)$, I am considering two related parameters, in fact, opposite in nature. I can have upper and lower bounds due to Nordhus-Gaddum relations, but I want to study the complexity results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see that computing $\alpha(G) + \omega(G)$ (for general $G$) is equivalent to computing $\alpha(G)$: given any graph $G$, construct $G'$ as the disjoint union of $G$ with $K_n$ where $n$ is the number of vertices of $G$.  Then we easily have $\omega(G') = n$ and $\alpha(G') = 1 + \alpha(G)$, so if you could compute $\alpha(G') + \omega(G')$...

Likewise, if you can compute $\alpha(G)$ in general, then you probably already know how to compute $\alpha(G) + \omega(G)$.

Comment: Thanks. Seems so simple now. Is there a similar transformation for finding $\chi(G)-\omega(G)$. If yes please allow me to figure it out :)